# Where was Kirito running to?

Tags: sword-art-online

In episode 1 of the anime, where was Kirito running to when Klein called out to him?

Klein called out to Kirito when they were both in the marketplace, and when Kirito turned into an alleyway.

Comment: just to confirm, was this before or after Kayaba appeared?

Comment: Before.  As soon as he got into the game.

Answer (score 3):

According to the first light novel he was heading to a weapons shop.

> After I had logged onto SAO, I started running through the
>   nostalgic stone paved roads of the «Starting City», headed for the
>   weapons shop. Realizing that I was a beta tester after seeing me start
>   and dash, Klein ran over without any hesitation.
>   *from chapter 2 of the first volume*